# Reiniciar el formulario

Tags: c#, asp

Para realizar un refresco de la pagina o limpiar todos los campos del formulario me podría funcionar en este caso.

[image]

Varios campos de texto, al pulsar en el botón finalizar debería reiniciar o limpiar todos los campos como empezar de nuevo.
He probado con:

```
Application.Restart();
```

pero no funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crearte tu propia función que borre los campos, sería algo como:

```
private void Clear()
{
  // así para todos tus textBox
  tuTextBox.Text=string.Empty;

  // así para todos tus comboBox
  tuComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;    

}
```

Y cuando pulses el botón, llama a esa función, de forma que se vaciarán.

Comment: Si gracias, para los campos (select) no me funcionan esta función, los campos terminan marcados como la ultima vez que el usuario lo dejo marcado

Comment: Te lo he editado para los comboBox, con el código actual se seleccionará el indice 0 ( el primer elemento)

Comment: Perfecto gracias

Comment: Si quieres que los combobox en lugar de seleccionar el primer elemento salgan en blanco usa tuComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;